# Django multiple profiles

Tags: django, python-3.x, relational-database

In what way can a Student submit an assignment to a particular Teacher(teaching a particular course)... What relationship we they have??

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/pictures/', blank=True)
    regex = RegexValidator(r'^\d{2}/\d{4}',
                           message='Required. 7 characters or fewer. This value must contain only numeric and slash.')
    matric_no = models.CharField(validators=[regex], blank=True, null=True, max_length=7, unique=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)  # validators should be a list
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female'),
        )


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/pictures/', blank=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)  # validators should be a list
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=False, default='M',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Maybe something like user messaging or mailing (User to User)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one `Student` can only submit a given assignment to only one `Teacher` (i.e., not to a group of teachers) you can use a model similar to the following:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    ...other fields...
```

You can also use a `ManyToMany` relation between `Student` and `Teacher` models and create your own [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table but semantically the method above makes more sense in this case.